# Pick item from listview, then swipe to view another activity

Tags: android, eclipse, android-viewpager, swipe

I am creating an app where you first have to choose an item from a list. The onItemClick then launches a new activity where an image is displayed. I now want to be able to do a swipe action in order to change to a new activity, or fragment. The new activity has nothing to do with the listview i.e i dont want to swipe to show the next item in the listview. I want to show a totally new activity. This new activity is the same for all items, no matter which item you choose in the listview.

I have been trying to use the viewpager, which i guess is sugested. Can't find a good guide for this though.

Do i add this in my single list item viewer layout? Or am i supposed to create a new java class and import my single list item activity into that class?

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

If you answer in code, please add comments inside the code, or outside. So that its easy to follow, since im not aware of all the things going on inside the code. Thanks in advace.

To clarify: Item is selected from a list --> A new activity is launched --swipe--> A new activity is displayed in fullscreen. I need help with the swiping part.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand what you're asking, but it sounds like you want to be working with [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) instead of full blown activities.  You can use the [titlepageindicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator) class to control swiping between fragments.  The viewpagerindicator library works with viewpagers to allow navigation between fragments.  Let me know if you need more details on how this works.

Here's a code sample in regards to using the viewpagerindicator:

```
public class EventTabsFragment extends Fragment {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mTitles = new ArrayList<String>();

    mTitles.add(getString(R.string.events_tabs_title_upcoming));
    mTitles.add(getString(R.string.events_tabs_title_recommended));
    mTitles.add(getString(R.string.events_tabs_title_local));
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tabbed, null, false);

    FragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new EventTabsAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    if(pager!=null) {
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    //note: the type of this indicator is dependent on the style of paging you want.  
    //the library I mentioned has multiple options in this regard
    TabPageIndicator indicator = (TabPageIndicator)view.findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    indicator.setViewPager(pager);

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
    return view;
}

class EventTabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public EventTabsAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        Fragment fragment = null;

        switch(position){

        case 0:
            fragment = EventFragment.newInstance(EventFragment.EVENTS_TYPE_UPCOMING);
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = EventFragment.newInstance(EventFragment.EVENTS_TYPE_RECOMMENDED);
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = EventFragment.newInstance(EventFragment.EVENTS_TYPE_LOCAL);
        default:
            break;
        }

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mTitles.get(position % mTitles.size()).toUpperCase();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mTitles.size();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: How do i transform my activity into a fragment? do i just change: "public class SingleListItem extends Activity {}" to "public class SingleListItem extends FragmentActivity {}"?

Comment: That's basically it.  You still need a base activity to manage the fragments.  In the sample code above, you can see that the view is using a fragment that runs more fragments.  This EventTabsFragment is still running in a base activity though.
Note: the main activity will handle navigation between fragments.  In order to do this properly you'll need to set up delegation in the main activity.  Let me know if you're not familiar with this.